# What is the equivalent of theme_menu_item in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I know that in drupal 6 exist: **theme_menu_item**, but in drupal 7 there is not. Is there any replacements so that I modify the output for main system menu ?

Actually I want to do a kind of filter of the menu items depending some criteria, which I will set in the function.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question to 'What is the equivalent of theme_menu_item in Drupal 7'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the function that called the theme function `theme_menu_item()` ([menu_tree_output()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/6)), and comparing it with the Drupal 7 version of the same function, I can say that the equivalent of `theme_menu_item()` is [theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7).

Comment: Thanks, I have put `function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables)` in `template.php` file from my theme, but it has no effect to menu. I have checked with debugger and the function is not processed by drupal, just as he doesn't recognize this hook...

Comment: @Ek Kosmos: `theme_menu_link()` is not a hook, but a theme function. Theme implementation needs to be registered using `hook_theme()`, as reported in [Default theme implementations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/group/themeable/7).

Comment: "Each module should provide a default implementation for theme_hooks that it registers. This implementation may be either a function or a template; if it is a function it must be specified via `hook_theme()`. By convention, default implementations of theme hooks are named `theme_HOOK`. Default template implementations are stored in the module directory."

Answer (score 4):

The theme_menu_item() function has been replaced by [theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_link/7). For details on this change, and all other changes made to the theme layer between Drupal 6 and 7, see the [Converting 6.x themes to 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/254940) page. There is also a [corresponding module conversion](http://drupal.org/node/224333) page.